# Components of velocity under impulsive motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, velocity, collision

I am getting confused when it comes to motion of two movable bodies joined by the ends of a string wherein one of them is given some velocity (making a certain angle to the string joining the bodies). When do we have to conserve linear momentum and when are the components of velocities equal?

For example in this question, after the mass $C$ moves towards right, such that BC makes an angle $120^o$ with $AB$, masses $B$ and $A$ move.

But then why is momentum not conserved along $BC$ rather the sum of components of velocities of $B$ (along $AB$ and perpendicular to $AB$) are equal to that of $C$ (along $v_0$ and perpendicular to $v_0$) along $BC$?

[image]